# Jmeter : random users are visible at parameterize script execution

Tags: regex, post, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and with the help of blogs and SOF, I could able to manage the record and parameterize the Script.

I am testing ASP.Net web application which uses Windows Authentication and AD.

The problem here is after execution in View Result Tree I can see the old user http page. For example I recorded the script with USer A and I parameterized all the varaible required to run the same script with user B. But at execution I can see User A session is loading and the data created by this transaction is corrupted which has some values of User A and User B.

I tried using Post processor >> Regular expression extractor for capturing ViewState and EventValidation and kept it back to post request  now error is resolved but transaction itself is not happening. No new data created after this change.

Please help me. I am confused now what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have hard-coded "Authorization" header which identifies all your virtual users as "User A". If it is the case - this header needs to be removed from all the requests and you need to construct a proper one with [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager).

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) to learn about how to properly setup JMeter for dealing with Active Directory logins. It is possible to parametrize usernames, passwords,domains, etc. as normal using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).